# Is current Simulink system model or subsystem in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-deployment

I have a .m file where I do some actions with Simulink model, and I would like to check if the currently used model is the entire model or a subsystem. Is there a specific syntax or function to check this? I need to be able to perform actions differently depending on Simulink system.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer it's about Simulink model and added the `simulink` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [bdroot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/bdroot.html) to get the name of the top level system and use string comparison to see if you have a subsystem or not:

```
sysname = 'f14/Actuator Model';
istoplevel = strcmp(bdroot(sysname), sysname);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isEntireModel = isequal( get_param( gcs, 'Type' ), 'block_diagram' );
```

Comment: where could I give the name of current system to know if it's model or subsystem

Comment: Replace the call to the `gcs` function with your system name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, after opening your model, or replace `gcs` with system name [make sure load it before using either with `load_system` or `open_system`]:

```
h=find_system(gcs,'FindAll',1,'SearchDepth',1,'BlockType','SubSystem');
if isempty(h)
    disp('Has Subsystems');
else
    disp('No Subsystems');
end
h=find_system(gcs,'FindAll',1,'SearchDepth',1,'BlockType','ModelReference');
if isempty(h)
    disp('Has Models');
else
    disp('No Models');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

easier way would be, say your model name is vdp, then:

bdIsLoaded('vdp')